# Perl Join Array After Second Element

Tags: perl, join, split

I want to get everything in a sentence after the second space. I am doing this by splitting and joining. I want to join everything after the second element but I'm not sure how to do this. The sentence can have several words so I don't want to hardcode the end range.

```
$sentence = "a b c and d";
@array = split(" ", $sentence);
$str = join(' ',$array[???]);
```

I want an output that looks like:

```
c and d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the array, you can `split` with a LIMIT, then just grab the last item (-1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $sentence = "a b c and d";
my $str = (split /\s+/, $sentence, 3)[-1];
print "$str\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Using *array slice* :

```perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $sentence = "a b c and d";
my @array = split(" ", $sentence);
my $str = join(' ', @array[2 .. $#array]);
print "$str\n";
```

`$#array` is the number/key of the last element of the array.

Check https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices